# microsoft.office.interop.excel stays in Process list

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

When I use the `microsoft.office.interop.excel` to create Excel file, I always call the `quit` command at the end. However, more than ever, if I look into the process list of Windows Task manager, I can clearly see that the process is still there and I end up with a bunch of those after a while.

I guess this isn't that much of a problem on normal case, but I would still like to prevent that from happening every time.

Is there any way to do this ?

I can't go on and kill all Excel process because some of them might really be application running and I can't really tell the difference between the two.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Comment: You're right. I'll close it.

Comment: I asked a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916137/best-way-to-release-excel-interop-com-object - Hope this helps.

Comment: You can refer to this article if it could help : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752

Comment: This article did help me :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752

Answer (score 3):

Notorious offender(automation)! To completely close the process you call  [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject({com object})](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) for all Word and Excel objects.

Comment: Does it still require me to enforce the "no 2 dot" rule ?

Comment: This method is the same as calling ReleaseComObject in a loop til it = 0. One stop shopping! Open, use, Quit, Marshal.Final..... and you don't need GC.Collect. I have tested this extensively.